# Must cross-entropy method's true distribution be in-family with the proposal distribution?

Tags: monte-carlo

The cross entropy method is used in rare event estimation, such as when estimating $$\mathbb{E}_u\left[H(X)\right] = \int H(x) f(x; u) dx\text{,}$$ where $H$ is some performance function and $f(x; u)$ is your true probability distribution from which $x$ is sampled.

The standard algorithm is to find the parameterization $v$ for which importance sampling gives the best convergence. Your importance sampling proposal distribution thus ends up being some $f(x; v)$.

My question is whether it matters that the true distribution must be representable as $f(x; u)$. Is there anything stopping us from using some other parametric distribution for our importance distribution?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out.

The proposal distribution does not need to be in-family with the true distribution.

The standard formulation in the original cross-entropy paper writes it up this way, which is also what is found on wikipedia, but in general it does not need to be the case. More generally, such as given in "Improving Aircraft Collision Risk Estimation using the Cross-Entropy Method," the true distribution $p(x)$ and the importance sampling distribution $q(x; v)$ need not be of the same family. The math works out the same for the cross entropy optimization step:

$$
v^{(t+1)} = \text{arg}\,\text{max}_v \frac{1}{N} \sum_i H(x_i) \frac{p(x_i)}{q(x_i; v^{(t)})} \ln q(x_i; v)
$$

Also note that in importance sampling, the proposal distribution also does not need to be in-family with the true distribution.